# How do you replace the "_" in the name of a list of keys from a dictionary as a result of doing a dict.keys()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, replace

I have the following code.....

```
@classmethod
def get_instruments_dict(cls):
    i_list = cls.get_instruments_list()
    i_keys = [x.name for x in i_list]


    #print(i_list)  ==> Result   [{'name': 'ZAR_JPY', 'type': 'CURRENCY', 'displayName': 'ZAR/JPY', 'pipLocation': 0.01, 'marginRate': '0.07'}, {'name': 'EUR_HUF', 'type': 'CURRENCY', 'displayName': 'EUR/HUF', 'pipLocation': 0.01, 'marginRate': '0.05'}....]

    #print (i_keys) ==>  Results ['ZAR_JPY', 'EUR_HUF', 'EUR_DKK', 'USD_MXN', 'GBP_USD', 'CAD_CHF', 'EUR_GBP'...........]

    df = pd.DataFrame(i_keys)

    print(df)  ==> Result

"""
|    |   0   |
|:---|:------|
|0   |ZAR_JPY|
|1   |EUR_HUF|
|2   |EUR_DKK|
|3   |USD_MXN|
|4   |GBP_USD|
|..  |    ...|
|63  |USD_PLN|
|64  |CAD_HKD|
|65  |GBP_CAD|
|66  |GBP_PLN|
|67  |       |
"""
    # I Tried the following with no luck.......................

    list = df.astype(str).tolist()

    print(list)  ==>   <bound method DataFrame.count of Empty DataFrame
                       Columns: []
                       Index: []>

    return {k:v for (k,v) in zip(i_keys, i_list) }
```

I would like to remove the "_" in each name of the df.  Maybe a loop of the DataFrame would work?  I can't seem to find an example of this with a List of keys.  It does not appear to be a way to use the index of this output.

End Result should look like this, as a usable DataFrame when done.......

| Index | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ZARJPY |
| 1 | EURHUF |
| 2 | EURDKK |
| 3 | USDMXN |
| 4 | GBPUSD |
| .. | ... |
| 63 | USDPLN |
| 64 | CADHKD |
| 65 | GBPCAD |
| 66 | GBPPLN |
| 67 |  |

Comment: Something like `df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('_', '')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty easy,

### Sample Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:['ZAR_JPY', 'EUR_HUF', 'EUR_DKK', 'USD_MXN', 'GBP_USD']})
print(df)
         0
0  ZAR_JPY
1  EUR_HUF
2  EUR_DKK
3  USD_MXN
4  GBP_USD
```

### Rename zero to `Names`:

```
df =  df.rename(columns={0: "Names"})
print(df)
     Names
0  ZAR_JPY
1  EUR_HUF
2  EUR_DKK
3  USD_MXN
4  GBP_USD
```

Use `replace`:

```
df['Names'] = df['Names'].str.replace("_", '')
print(df)
    Names
0  ZARJPY
1  EURHUF
2  EURDKK
3  USDMXN
4  GBPUSD
```

In case, you are looking for `Index` as column as well..

```
df.index.names = ['Index']
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
   Index   Names
0      0  ZARJPY
1      1  EURHUF
2      2  EURDKK
3      3  USDMXN
4      4  GBPUSD
```

### Or In a Single line:

```
df = df.rename(columns={0: "Names"}).replace("_", '').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks, Giving it a Try Now, sorry for delay.........

Comment: lol, Perfect. So the trick was to "Rename" the columns before applying a method?  I am a self taught Pythonic enthusiast, so the PAIN I go through is unfathomable.

Comment: @DavisRogers,  Yes, because its unnamed column as `0` so, better to rename that to a valid desired column name that will be easy for further column based operation.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) + [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) + [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

#### Using comprehension-list:

```
# If name key is not in the dictionary, then 'Not found' will be returned.
df_output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name'], data=[d.get('name', 'Not found').replace("_","") for d in i_list]).reset_index()
print(df_output)
```

#### Without comprehension-list:

```
data = []
for d in i_list:
  name = d.get('name', 'Not found').replace("_","")
  data.append(name)
df_output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name'], data=data).reset_index()
print(df_output)
```

**EDIT:**
If you want the index as a new column in the final dataframe, so you should add: [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method. I have update the code above with this new feature.

Output:

|  | index | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | ZARJPY |
| 1 | 1 | EURHUF |

Comment: Thanks for the piece of code.  You start with a open list and loop through with the replace.   'Not found' is throwing me for a loop.  However, I am about done with the script.  As you see, I am engulfing the entire market to run my strategy against all Time Frames.  Are you available to take a look at this code.  I am not too sharp with OOP and I am a little tangled up.  Can we connect?  I have not read the policy on collaboration outside of this platform?  Do you know the rules pertaining to this?  Or is there a Discord Channel that work along side this platform?  That would be pretty cool.